# Mailcore MCOIMAPSession with hyperpma.com mail server (host.hyperpma.info)

Tags: ios, email, ios8, mailcore2

I had used `Mailcore` library to receive and sent email on one my iOS application.
However,I got success it to use with popular email server like Gmail,Ymail and Hotmail.

Now I am trying to use that library to fetch emails from mail server [host.hyperpma.info] or other email server.

This is my following code:

```
MCOIMAPSession *session = [[MCOIMAPSession alloc] init];
    [session setHostname:@"host.hyperpma.info"];
    [session setPort:993];
    [session setUsername:self.txtEmail.text];
    [session setPassword:self.txtPassword.text];
    [session setConnectionType:MCOConnectionTypeTLS];//I also try MCOConnectionTypeStartTLS
    [session setCheckCertificateEnabled:NO];

 MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind requestKind = MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders|MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindFlags;

    NSString *folder = @"INBOX";
    MCOIndexSet *uids = [MCOIndexSet indexSetWithRange:MCORangeMake(1, UINT64_MAX)];

    MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation *fetchOperation = [session fetchMessagesOperationWithFolder:folder requestKind:requestKind uids:uids];
    //    [SVProgressHUD show];


    [fetchOperation start:^(NSError * error, NSArray * fetchedMessages, MCOIndexSet * vanishedMessages) {
        //Let's check if there was an error:
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"Error downloading message headers:%@", error);

        }

    }];
```

I am getting Error as below :

```
Error downloading message headers:Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=1 "A stable connection to the server could not be established." UserInfo=0x7fa6a1e3cdc0 {NSLocalizedDescription=A stable connection to the server could not be established.}
```

Am I missing something in code or settings?

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: I've been able to connect to it using: `openssl s_client -connect host.hyperpma.info:993 -crlf` on the command line. It sounds like you have an issue with your ISP.

Comment: I already used same email account on my ios default mail application with same sever detail.I am using my iphone in my same ISP,it working properly with it.

I also tried to check get some error log with Connectionlogger but it does not seem to get connected.